# How do I assign a function that returns a value to a variable?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

So I have a class called Transactions and I put all my functions there.  The problem is, when I try to call that specific function and assign it to a variable, there is a "ByRef Argument Type mismatch" error that keeps on bugging me. Help please :)

```
Public Function GetUserID(name As String) As Integer
    Dim gotID As Integer
    Dim rec As Recordset
    Call connectDB
    sSQL = "select ID from User where Name ='" & name & "'"
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    gotID = rec(0)
    GetUserID = gotID
End Function

Private Sub btnAcctAdd_Click()
    Dim tr As Transactions
    Set tr = New Transactions

    Dim ID as Integer
    Dim name, username, password As String

    name = cmbName.Value
    'MsgBox name
    ID = tr.GetUserID(name)
    'MsgBox ID
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is, only password is being declared as string, the other 2 are object.

So change the code to this and the error will go away:

```
Dim name As String, username As String, password As String
```

Comment: Actually, the other two variables in the original code are Variant, not Object.